# Reference for CW-Complexes

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation, cw-complexes

I am taking a class on algebraic topology, and this concept was introduced quite quickly: it was the subject of a week's lecture and then we just kept on using it during the exercises. And now I still feel I don't have an intuitive feel for it. I am looking for some reference where CW-Complexes are treated in detail, with as many examples as possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A class on topological algebra or on algebraic topology? :)

Comment: Sorry I got confused with homological algebra, I just edited the question :)

Comment: Just emailed my topology professor, hopefully he can help

Comment: @user404944 Allen Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" is always a nice resource. It is available online for free: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf Chapter 0 is what you may be looking for. It isn't always strictly formal but examples and exercises are first class.

Comment: For finite cell complexes together with a background in adjunction spaces see the book http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hatcher's book ([https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](https://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf)) is one of my favorite algebraic topology book, it has a lot of examples. For a precise and detailed first exposition on CW-complexes i suggest this book of James W. Vick, Homology Theory
An Introduction to Algebraic Topology (https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387941264) and the book of James R. Munkres Elements of Algebraic Topology (https://books.google.it/books/about/Elements_of_Algebraic_Topology.html?id=FoplRBTu7wwC&redir_esc=y) which give a precise and formal description of the main properties and the inductive construction of CW-complexes.